# Zend redirector not working properly

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

I have just uploaded my app into a shared hosting environment and it does not seem to be working properly.
I have 2 plugins registered. One checks for session timeout and the other check for session is created  after logged in.
the pproblem is that after the second plugin(security.php) kicks in it suppose to redirect the user to the login screen  because session has not been created yet. Upon redirection the page displays :The page isn't redirecting properly.
I am not sure what is happenning since everything works fine locally.Below are my two files i mentioned here.
Security.php(here you can see that i have tried couple options, but nothing worked).

```
class Plugins_security extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch (Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
        //$vc = new Zend_Application_Resource_View();
        if ($request->getModuleName() != "auth")
        {
            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            if (! $auth->hasIdentity())
            {
                //$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                //'redirector');
                $flashMessenger = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
                $flashMessenger->addMessage(array('message' => 'Sua sess&atilde;o expirou. Favor logar novamente', 'status' => 'info'));
                //$this->_redirect('/auth/login/',array(‘code’ => 301));

                $r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
                $r->gotoSimple("index", "login", "auth");
                //header('Location: /auth/login/'); 
                //return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

timeout.php

```
class Plugins_timeout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    protected $_auth = null;
    protected $_acl = null;
    protected $_flashMessenger = null;
    protected static $_ZEND_SESSION_NAMESPACE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS= 900;



    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
    Zend_Session::start();
    $moduleName = parent::getRequest()->getModuleName();
    if($moduleName !='auth'){
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > self::$_ZEND_SESSION_NAMESPACE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minates ago
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the runtime

    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $_baseUrl=$front->getBaseUrl();
    Zend_Debug::dump(time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']);
    header("Location:$_baseUrl/auth/login/index/timeout/1" );

    }else{
            $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']= time();
        }
    }   
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. I need to deploy this app ASAP.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
$r = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');
$r->gotoSimpleAndExit("index", "login", "auth"); // Note the 'AndExit' suffix.
```

`$r->gotoXXX()` just sets the correct header and codes in the `$response` object, but allows the rest of the dispatch to continue. In contrast, the `AndExit` part immediately sends the response to the client and exits.

[Not clear why `AndExit` would not be required in your local environment, though...]

Comment: thank you David  i gave it a try but i am still having the same problem "302 error" do you have another option?I confirmed the 302 error by running a Charles session(proxying tool). thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I understand precisely what you mean by a "302 error". Is it from ZF or from Apache?

Comment: Hello David, it was coming for Apache. I was able to solve it using a different approach. Instead of redirecting i am setting the module, controller and action using the request object. that worked great.

$request->setModuleName('auth')->setControllerName('Login')->setActionName('index')->setParams(array('timeout'=>'1','msg'=>''));
thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution that works for you. Thanks and cheers!